# Should ex-spouse be paying tax on her portion of my private pension?

Tags: taxes, canada, income

My ex wife has been receiving a portion of my private company pension for about 5 years now. I have just realized recently I have been taxed on the full amount of both our monthly pension amounts. Shouldn't she be paying the taxes on her portion? Also the entire portion of the pension shows up on my yearly taxes, which it shouldn't be.

Comment: Do you mean an actual defined benefits pension scheme run by a private company? I ask because such things are very rare in Canada.

Comment: Also, are these payments going to her because you have agreed to pay her some amount (alimony, for example) or because that's how the pension was structured from the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

This is going to depend on how the support agreement is structured. In short, if there is no court order mandating payments, you will be taxed fully and your ex-spouse not at all. For most court-mandated spousal support payments and in some cases child-support cases, you may be able to deduct the portion paid as support, and your ex-spouse would include as income.

See here per CRA guidance:
https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/about-your-tax-return/support-payments/what-amount-claim-report.html

"

**Spousal support payments**

*Generally, support payments made under a court order or written agreement for the maintenance of the recipient are taxable to the recipient and deductible by the payer if both of the following situations apply:*

- *The order or agreement clearly states the amount to be paid for the current or former spouse or common-law partner.*
- *All payments for child support are fully paid for the current and previous years.*

"

Further details on how to document this with the CRA can be found here: https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/about-your-tax-return/support-payments/registering-your-court-order-written-agreement.html

If you think you have been taxed improperly in prior years, you can refile your old tax returns with the corrected information. Instructions on how to do so can be found here: https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/about-your-tax-return/change-your-return.html

Comment: Note that even if you ultimately claim a deduction for the portion of pension paid as alimony, it would still show up as 'your income' and then be reduced by a deduction.